# Where can I set cardinality for a custom field?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom field defined in a module I am writing, which works correctly. The default cardinality is unlimited and I want to limit it to 1.

I am sure I need to call `setCardinality(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::1)` somewhere, but I can't understand where exactly I should add that call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can limit a custom field to single value by defining a cardinality in the annotations of the field type.

I don't know if you can find this in the docs, but you can use the core comment field as example:

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'comment' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "comment",
 *   label = @Translation("Comments"),
 *   description = @Translation("This field manages configuration and presentation of comments on an entity."),
 *   list_class = "\Drupal\comment\CommentFieldItemList",
 *   default_widget = "comment_default",
 *   default_formatter = "comment_default",
 *   cardinality = 1,
 * )
 */
class CommentItem extends FieldItemBase implements CommentItemInterface {
```

When you add a comment field to a content type the cardinality form element is hidden and instead this message is displayed:

> **Allowed number of values**
>
> This field cardinality is set to 1 and cannot be configured.

Comment: Thank you. This does it. Sadly, "I don't know if you can find this in the docs" seems to be a common answer in Drupal 8.

Comment: Looks like it's [not in the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-a-custom-field-0/create-a-custom-field-type). It's in the code comments (it'll be in the annotation class), but you have to know to look there first which is pretty much guess work until you've found it once